# Rooting Samsung Galaxy A3 2016 (SM-A310F)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-a3

How can I root the [Samsung Galaxy A3 2016 (SM-A310F)](http://www.samsung.com/fr/smartphones/galaxy-a3-2016-a310f/SM-A310FZKAXEF/)?

Andoid version is Marshmallow (6.0.1) and my computer runs on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

**[ROOTING YOUR PHONE](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/205801) WILL PROBABLY VOID YOUR WARRANTY FROM BOTH THE CARRIER AND THE MANUFACTURER. IF YOU DO NOT WISH TO ACCEPT FAULT FOR ANY ADVERSE EFFECTS OF ROOTING, THEN DO NOT READ ANY FURTHER.**

### Downloads and installs

- [Samsung USB Drivers](http://odindownload.com/SamsungUSBDriver/USB_Drivers_1.5.27.0.rar).
- [Odin](http://odindownload.com/download/Odin3_v3.10.6.zip).
- [Root File](https://download.chainfire.eu/933/CF-Root/CF-Auto-Root/CF-Auto-Root-a3xelte-a3xeltexx-sma310f.zip).
- Install Samsung drivers and unzip Odin and Root File.

### Phone Setting

- Turn on developer mode:

  > Settings > About device > Sofware info > Build number.
  >   **Tap build number 7 times.**
- Enable USB debugging:

  > Settings > Developer options > USB debugging.
  >   **Turn on.**
- Enable OEM (very important!):

> Settings >  Developer options > OEM unlock.
>   **Allow the device to be OEM unlocked.**
>   This has to be turned on for ever from now! Reports said without this options phones have turned into bricks.

### Rooting

- Turn your phone off, then turn it on in **download mode**.

  > Press and hold together Volume Down, Home and Power.
- Connect the phone to the computer.
- Start Odin and select **AP**, then browse to the Root File.
- Press **Start** and the rooting will process.

Comment: Note that for Galaxy A3 2017 (SM-A320F) with Android 8 these instructions are **not sufficient**! Namely, in addition to OEM unlocking, you must disable RMM to prevent bricking your device after flashing custom binaries. See [this page](https://forum.xda-developers.com/samsung-a-series-2017/how-to/guide-root-install-twrp-samsung-t3747535) for details.